# Error en if-else con Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, condiciones, else

Código:

```
A = input("Ingrese su calificación: ")
if A < 6:
  print("Reprobado")
elif A > 8:
  print("Aprobado sobresaliente")
else:
  print("Aprobado")
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que convertir el string en entero para poder comparar, para eso puedes definir así: `A = int(input('Ingrese su calificación: '))`

Comment: ¿Y para un real?

Comment: Para un real `float(input('...'))`